How to solve error "AADB2C90011" when using a custom signup user flow in Microsoft Entra?
I am creating a VSTO plugin in VB.net. I would like allow users to sign-up and sign-in, using their Microsoft Office account.
So I turned my attention to MSAL (in VB.net) and to Microsoft Entra (its online counterpart).
In Microsoft Entra, I have:

Registered an app.

I configured to accept "Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts"
In the app's properties, I switched "Assignment required" to "no"
Created APIs and granted administrator constent
Added a custom return API (localhost - I'm working on a desktop app)


Created a "Sign-up and sign-in" user flow (sometimes also called the "policy"). I have associated it with the app I just described. As far as I know, creating a policy and associating it with an Enterprise Application is the only way to allow new users to sign-up into the application (otherwise, you have to add them manually to you application's users list).

In my VSTO addin's code, I am then using the following lines:
'''
Dim clientId As String = "<client-id>" 
Dim tenantId As String = "<directory-id>"
Dim tenantName As String = "<string-name>"
Dim signUpSignInPolicy As String = "<user-flow-name>"
Dim authority As String = $"https://{tenantName}.b2clogin.com/tfp/{tenantName}.onmicrosoft.com/{signUpSignInPolicy}"
Dim redirectUri As String = "http://localhost"

Dim pcaOptions As PublicClientApplicationOptions = New PublicClientApplicationOptions With
{
    .ClientId = clientId,
    .TenantId = tenantId
}

Return PublicClientApplicationBuilder.CreateWithApplicationOptions(pcaOptions) _
                                     .WithB2CAuthority(authority) _
                                     .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri) _
                                     .Build()

'''
However, I get the error AADB2C90011, according to which "The client id  provided in the request does not match client id 4829629c-4ae8-42a5-9def-bd28fbfd6992 registered in policy."
Does anyone have already faced this issue? I found this online forum that seems to say that it's a bug that is still ongoing... but I believe many people never encountered it. So I guess some of you might have done things differently and/or found a workaround.
